# How do i move each item one index up automatic in a listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, indexing

This is my code in `Form1` constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
    header.Text = "";
    header.Name = "col1";
    listView1.Columns.Add(header);
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.Scrollable = true;
    readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");

    lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n").ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(lines[i]);
    }
    header.AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);

    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var currentIndex = listView1.SelectedItems[i].Index;
        var item = listView1.Items[i];
        if (currentIndex > 0)
        {
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
            listView1.Items.Insert(currentIndex - 1, item);
        }
    }
```

In the FOR loop I'm getting error since `listView1.SelectedItems[i].Index;` cannot be `0` for index.

My goal is to move smoothly and slowly each item in the `listBox1` up one place and the item under it to push up and so on all the items in a endless loop when the last item get to the top from the bottom repeat it again with the first item. Like a row marquee effect.

How can i do it ?

This is what I've tried.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RssNewsFeeder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int lastIndex;
        string readableRss;
        private List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
            header.Text = "";
            header.Name = "col1";
            listView1.Columns.Add(header);
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.Scrollable = true;
            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");

            lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n").ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(lines[i]);
            }
            header.AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
            timer1.Enabled = true;           
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Refresh();
            int i = listView1.TopItem == null ? -1 : listView1.TopItem.Index;
            if (i > -1)
            {
                if (i == lastIndex || i == listView1.Items.Count - 2) i = 0;
                lastIndex = i;
                listView1.TopItem = listView1.Items[++i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added a timer and inside the timer tick event I'm doing it.
Its working but the problem it doesn't moving smooth but the lines jump each time one place up. I want it to move smooth like in the end of a movie when you see the credits moving up.

What should I change/add in the timer tick event code ?

EDIT**

This is what i did now in the timer tick event:

```
this.Invalidate();
            var r = Enumerable.Empty<ListViewItem>();

            if (this.listView1.Items.Count > 0)
                r = this.listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>();

            var last = r.LastOrDefault();

            if (last != null)
            {
                listView1.Items.Insert(0, last);
                listView1.Items.Remove(last);
            }
```

But im getting exception: Cannot add or insert the item '' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: That's twisted ! Can i ask you why you need this ?

Comment: Its a News Feeder im using Rss from a new site. So i want the user to see the news to see it moving automatic instead each time scroll down with the mouse. Since the news will be update each time so i want it to be automatic.

Comment: Updated my question with what i did so far.

Comment: Anyway, why don't you use `Items.Insert(0, lastitem)` and remove your last item ?

Comment: In the timer tick event ?

Comment: Yes. It would insert your last item in first position (at the top of your listview) and then you can delete it in last position. And so on, in your timer

Comment: Justin can you look please at my question i just updated it with what i tried like you said but im getting exception.

Comment: You need to swap the insert and remove lines around. Remove it First, then Insert it. That should stop the Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way in your timer:

```
int count;
if ((count = listView1.Items.Count) > 0)
{
   var LastItem = listView1.Items[count - 1];
   listView1.Items.Remove(LastItem);
   listView1.Items.Insert(0, LastItem);
}
```

Comment: Justin im getting exception on the line : listView1.Items.Insert(0, LastItem); Cannot add or insert the item '' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it